# Is it OK to close() Cursor object and than set a new value to it?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I m trying to understand a RecyclerView.Adapter implementation i need to use, where the dataset is a Cursor object.
But some of the logic is not clear to me with regard to closing a Cursor object and than setting it to a different value.
What exactly is happening in close()?
Is this O.K. ?

```
   public void setCursor(Cursor cursor){
        mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mMyContentObserverr);
        mCursor.close();

        mCursor = cursor;
        mCursor.registerContentObserver(mMyContentObserverr);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Or should i play safe like this:

```
   public void setCursor(Cursor cursor){
        Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        oldCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mMyContentObserverr);
        oldCursor.close();

        mCursor = cursor;
        mCursor.registerContentObserver(mMyContentObserverr);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

What are the benefits of using oldCursor?
Is there any danger in closing and setting on the same Cursor object?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code you included are functionally equivalent. The line

```
Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
```

creates a new `Cursor` reference that points to the same object, that is, `mCursor` and `oldCursor` have the same location in memory. Since they're the same object, `oldCursor.close()` is exactly the same as `mCursor.close()`.

However, when you set `mCursor` to `cursor`, `mCursor` no longer refers to the cursor that was closed; it now refers to the same object as `cursor`. Any operations that you perform on the new `mCursor` will not be affected by the old `mCursor` in any way.

As for which version you should use, I personally would stick with the first version. However, if you feel the code is more clear by creating `oldCursor`, by all means, go for it. It's exactly the same.